# Estimation of order of sum-covering subset

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

This question is from Tao and Vu's book, Exercise 1.1.7., which is part of the chapter "The probabilistic method".

The problem is:

**Problem.** Consider a nonempty subset $A$ of finite abelian group $(Z,+)$. Show that there exists a subset $\{v_1,v_2, ..., v_d\}$ of $Z$ with $d=O(\log\frac{|Z|}{|A|}+\log\log(10+|Z|))$ such that
\begin{equation}
 A+\{0,1\}^d \cdot (v_1,v_2, ..., v_d)=\{a+\sum u_i v_i | a\in A, u_i=0 \ \text{or} \ 1 \}=Z.
\end{equation}

I tried to solve this problem, but I am having a hard time to improve this. I'd like to introduce my attempt:

I used the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $A,B$ be nonempty subsets of $Z$, then there exists an $x\in Z$ such that
\begin{equation}
1-\frac{|A\cup(B+x)|}{|Z|}\leq \left( 1-\frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\left( 1-\frac{|B|}{|Z|}\right).
\end{equation}

Proof: Let us choose $x$ uniformly random from $Z$ and $(B+x)=B'$. Then $E(|A\cup B'|)=E(|A|+|B'|-|A\cap B'|)$ $=E(|A|)+E(|B'|)-E(|A\cap B'|)$, and $E(|A\cap B'|)=\sum_{x\in Z} P(x\in A\cap B')=\sum_{x\in Z} P(x\in A)P(x\in B')$ $=\displaystyle\sum_{x\in Z}\frac{|A||B'|}{|Z|^2}=|A||B'|/|Z|$. Since $|B'|=|B|$, we deduce $E\left(1-\displaystyle\frac{|A\cup(B')|}{|Z|}\right)= \left( 1-\displaystyle\frac{|A|}{|Z|}\right)\left( 1-\displaystyle\frac{|B|}{|Z|}\right)$.

Now let $A_i=A_{i-1}\cup (A_{i-1}+v_i)$. Then clearly $A_0=A$ and $A_d=A+\{0,1\}^d \cdot (v_1,v_2, ..., v_d)$.
By lemma, we can choose $v_i$ such that $$1-|A_i|/|Z|\leq (1-|A_{i-1}|/|Z|)^2,$$ or $$|A_i|\geq |A_{i-1}|(2-|A_{i-1}|/|Z|).$$ Using this inequality inductively, we get $|A_d|\geq \prod_{1\leq i\leq d}(2-|A_{i-1}|/|{Z}|)|A_0|$. Now, since we can choose $v_i$ such that $|A_i|\gneq|A_{i-1}|$ (if |A_i|=|A_{i-1}|, adding $v_i$ is actually meaningless.), so *at least* $$|A_d|\geq \prod_{1\leq i \leq d}\left(1+i/|Z|\right) |A_0|.$$
Taking logarithm at both side, we get $\log|A_d|\geq\sum_{1\leq i\leq d}\log(1+i/|Z|)+\log|A|$. We have to choose $d$ satisfying $|A_d|\geq|Z|$ so that $A_d=Z$, so let's find such $d$ with $\sum_{1\leq i\leq d}\log(1+i/|Z|)+\log|A|\geq \log |Z|$.
I want to estimate 'well' $$\sum_{1\leq i\leq d}\log(1+i/|Z|)\sim\int_1^d \log(1+\frac{x}{|Z|})dx\sim (|Z|+d)\log(1+\frac{d}{|Z|})-d$$ so that we can find inequality of $d$.

I am having trouble to make this inequality into usable form.

Also, I worry the assumption of *at least* part that bounds $|A_d|\geq \prod_{1\leq i \leq d}\left(1+i/|Z|\right) |A_0|$ is overkilling.

Another question, I am undergraduate student and not mathematically mature yet. However, I am very fascinated to analytic number theory and additive combinatorics. I am also interested in ergodic number theory, or ergodic Ramsey theory. However, in my university, classes about these subjects merely opens, so I have to self-study these subjects. Are there any recommendations about studying materials, or curriculums, or anything else?

Any helps will be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right construction, just need to arrange the derivation of the final bound a little differently.

Let $\alpha=\lvert A\rvert/\lvert Z\rvert$ and, in general, $\alpha_i=\lvert A_i\rvert/\lvert Z\rvert$. By the construction you outline, with $A_0=A$ and $A_i = A + \{0,1\}^i\cdot (v_1,\ldots,v_i)$ for some suitable choice of $v_i$ we can iteratively ensure that

$$ 1- \alpha_{i+1}\leq (1-\alpha_i)^2.$$

While $\alpha_i\leq 1/2$ this implies that $\alpha_{i+1}\geq \frac{3}{2}\alpha_i$, and so in general $\alpha_d \geq (3/2)^d\alpha$. In particular, there is $d=O(\log(1/\alpha))$ such that $\alpha_d\geq 1/2$.

We now continue the same procedure, but now notice that $(1-\alpha_d)\leq 1/2$, and so in general this iteration will give
$$ 1-\alpha_{d+k} \leq 2^{-2^k}.$$

In particular after $k=O(\log\log \lvert Z\rvert)$ steps we have $1-\alpha_{d+k}< 1/\lvert Z\rvert$, and so $\lvert A_{d+k}\rvert > \lvert Z\rvert-1$, and hence $A_{d+k}=Z$ as required.